# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr<User>', is a potentially non-nullable type. Try adding

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

My Login Page Code:

```
_auth.signIn(mail.text, password.text).then((value) => {
    debugPrint('User E-Mail: ${value.email}')
});
```

My Service  Code:

```
  Future<User>signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {

      var user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return user.user;

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      errorhHandle(e.code);
    }
  }
```

Error: [View Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjWDI.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `return` statement in the `catch` block, which means it returns nothing or `null`, while your method signature says that it that returns a `User` or  `Future<User>`.

You'll have to return a `User` or `Future<User>` from the catch block, throw an error, or (simplest) mark the method as potentially returning `null` with `Future<User?>`.